# Two seemingly unrelated puzzles have very similar solutions; what's the connection?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, puzzle

I think it's an interesting coincidence that the [locker puzzle](http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu/mathworks/Locker_Puzzle.pdf) and this [puzzle about duplicate array entries (see problem 6b)](http://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/Emissary/0308/puzzles.pdf) have such similar solutions.  *Spoiler alert!* Don't read on if you want to solve these puzzles yourself first (they're two of the best puzzles I've ever seen).

In both solutions we consider a collection of labeled boxes, each with a number inside, and then "traverse through boxes" by starting at a given box and using the number inside to decide where to go next.  For example, we might start at box $1$, find the number $5$ inside, proceed to box $5$, find the number $2$ inside, proceed to box $2$, and so forth.

Furthermore, in both solutions we "traverse through boxes" for the same reason: we're interested in finding cycles.  More specifically, for the locker puzzle, we're interested in the question, *"If we start at box $n$, how many steps does it take to get back to box $n$?"*, and for the duplicate array puzzle, we're interested in the question, *"Does there exist $n$ such that (1) if we start at box $1$, we will eventually get to box $n$, and (2) if we start at box $n$, we will eventually get back to box $n$?"*

Since the two puzzles seem quite unrelated at first glance, I'll pose the following question:

> Is there a deep reason why "traversing through boxes" (described in the 2nd paragraph above) shows up in the solution for both of these puzzles?

In addition,

> Are there other interesting problems for which "traversing through boxes", whether to find cycles or for any other reason, shows up in the solution?

[Edit] I mistakenly said that for the locker puzzle, we're interested in the question, *"If we start at box $n$, will we eventually get back to box $n$?"*  Instead, the question should be, *"If we start at box $n$, how many steps does it take to get back to box $n$?"*

[Edit] Thanks for all the great answers so far!  However, I'm still not completely convinced there's nothing more going on here...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of a deep connection; from what I gather, it is merely the case that the locker puzzle and problem 6 have a common subproblem, which is: prove that "traversing through boxes" produces a cycle, i.e., leads us to visit a node we have already visited. In the locker puzzle, there is an extra restriction that this cycle include the starting node. This restriction holds because the locker puzzle involves a permutation, while problem 6 does not necessarily involve a permutation.

Unless I'm missing something, problems 6a and 6b can be solved simultaneously using the "traverse through boxes" technique starting at array index 1, despite the comment that "Part (b) seems to be a lot harder than part (a), and it apparently requires entirely different techniques". Since the hedge words "seems" and "apparently" were used, we can't say that the comment is false, but nonetheless, I believe it would be false without those hedge words. The key idea is that, as explained in the PDF on the locker puzzle, "player $ B_i $ never opens a locker (other than locker i) without first finding its number, so each time he opens a new locker he must find either his own number or the number of another unopened locker". The same basic reasoning applies to problem 6, with just slight modifications.

Problem 6 can be made to look a little more like the locker puzzle by taking a[1] out of the picture. We can consider b = {a[2], ... , a[n]} as the "real" array with m = n - 1 elements, and the value a[1] as the index of the start node. We can further relabel {2, ... , n} as {1, ... , m} if desired.

All we care about is finding a cycle, that is, coming across a value that is an index we have already visited. This is equivalent to finding a duplicate in array a, since the indices we visited are precisely array values in a. We can fulfill the time and memory requirements using a boolean array of size m. The boolean array allows us to see if we have visited an index yet, and <strike>of course has constant memory and</strike> is fast. (**Correction:** the boolean array would have linear memory, not constant. Evidently there is a better way to solve this.) We are guaranteed not to visit any array index twice, so the algorithm has linear time. If we didn't think of a boolean array, we might be tempted to use some sort of a list structure with fast insert and find, but a boolean array is faster.

To tie the problems together further, we can interpret the data as a directed graph where each vertex has outdegree 1. In the locker puzzle, the indegree for each vertex is also 1, but problem 6 has no such restriction.

The outdegree being 1 guarantees that we can traverse from one vertex to another without any ambiguity. Beyond that, we need to guarantee a cycle will occur regardless of where we start.

A permutation is partitioned into cycles, so this allows us to conclude for the locker puzzle that we will find our cycle precisely when we get back to the starting node. For problem 6, we are guaranteed to find some cycle, because otherwise we would have to go on endlessly, but the array is finite, so that is absurd.

Maybe my answer should be made more rigorous, but I hope it is at least satisfactory and accurate. If not, let me know, and I'll try to fix it. I admit that after looking at this problem for an extended period of time, my mind is getting a bit foggy..

**EDIT**: Oh I think I figured out how to solve 6b with constant memory. You can follow n - 1 links, thus covering n (not necessarily distinct) array indices of a, and by this time you are guaranteed to be in the middle of a cycle. Note your current array index. Then go around until you see that index again, which will give you the period of the cycle. Then using this you can find the "entry node" of the cycle, which will be your duplicate. (Use modular arithmetic.) I haven't worked it out in detail but I believe that's an accurate sketch.

Comment: In the case where only one entry is duplicated, I imagine you could just sum the array values and subtract $2 + 3 + \ldots + n$ to find the duplicate entry :)  OK, so technically that requires storing an integer on the order of n^2 (which might not be allowed), but I'm going to sweep that one under the rug because on any "real" computer that would be the sensible thing to do...

Comment: Some great insights here!  I definitely agree with you that both graphs and permutations come up.  In fact, I would argue that these insights are vital for _solving_ the puzzles in the first place.  However, I disagree with you on a few points.  In particular, I don't think that (1) a boolean array of size m is constant memory, or that (2) removing a[1] makes problem 6b look like the locker puzzle (since the cycle in problem 6b could start anywhere in the array, while you're always stuck in a cycle for the locker puzzle).

Comment: Finally, if there's truly no deep connection, I think that "why do they have this common subproblem and where else does this subproblem come up" would still be an interesting question.

Comment: @Elliott(1), yes that is a very sensible thing to do, and I hadn't thought of it. :) The parenthetical at the end of 6a's problem statement is a bit odd; perhaps they had yet another solution in mind. We can get around the integer size restriction on a technicality; simply start with -(2 + ... + n) and add the array elements to that! Or we could alternate addition and subtraction. I still find the PDF's comment rather misleading, since the solution for 6b meets all the requirements for 6a.

Comment: @Elliott(2), thanks. Regarding your points: (1) You're right, it's linear, not constant. Hmm, I guess I haven't solved it then. (2) I think removing a[1] makes problem 6 look *more* like the locker puzzle than it would otherwise. The value 1 appears nowhere in a, so the graph for problem 6 for array a cannot possibly be a permutation. However, if we omit a[1] to obtain array b, then that can be a permutation. For example, Let a = {2, 5, 4, 3, 2}. Regarding comment (3), yes I'm interested too. I didn't mean to dismiss the possibility of deep connection. I'd be happy to learn of one.

Comment: Your updated solution definitely works!

Comment: @Elliott: Some moderately similar problems include finding the nth digit of the decimal expansion of a given rational number, or finding the nth Fibonacci number mod m for some m, but I think the resemblance for these is mostly superficial. Another marginally similar problem is using cycles to determine whether a set is well defined according to the axiom of regularity. This can be done with depth first search in conjunction with a boolean array. I'm having a hard time thinking of more directly similar problems. My experience is not too extensive.

Comment: @Elliot @Mitch I do think that 6(a) is substantially easier, even with the parenthetical constraint: sum the array values modulo $n$.

Answer (score 2):

You might also enjoy this one, which is, I think, easier than the two you have linked to: you are starting with a pack of $n$ cards, numbered from 1 to $n$, but in a random order. You now play the following game: you look at the top card, numbered $i$, say, then you put the card into the $i$-th position from top. Repeat the whole procedure. Clearly, if at some point the top card it numbered 1, nothing interesting happens any more and the position of the cards never changes after that point. Prove that, independently of the starting configuration, after finitely many steps, the 1 will turn up on the top.

Comment: Thanks, this is really interesting!  Here's a sketch of my solution; please let me know if there's a more elegant approach. _Lemma_: if the first $k$ cards don't contain card $1$, then every one of those $k$ cards will reach the top at some point (induction on $k$).  Now suppose card $1$ is in position $k+1$.  One of the first $k$ cards must be $>k$.  After that card reaches the top (guaranteed by the Lemma), the next step will send that card below card $1$, and card $1$ will get closer to the top.  Since $k$ was arbitrary, this process will continue until card $1$ is at the top.

Comment: That works. Another way of formulating the same idea is: there are only finitely many possible configurations and each configuration determines the next uniquely. So, any game must eventually fall into a cycle. Let $k\neq 1$ be the highest number that appears at the top in the course of this cycle. After it comes to the top, it goes into the $k$-th place. By assumption, all other numbers are smaller, so this number will never be touched again - contradicting the cycle assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested for more puzzles, here is one which is an algorithmic puzzle.

You are given an array of $\displaystyle 2n$ elements: $$a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n , b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$$

You need to rearrange the elements of the array to look like: $$b_1, a_1, b_2, a_2, \dots, b_n , a_n$$

It is trivial by using an extra array, but the hard part of the puzzle is that you need to do it in $\displaystyle \mathcal{O}(1)$ (or to be pedantic, $\displaystyle \mathcal{O}(\log n))$ space and $\displaystyle \mathcal{O}(n)$ time.

(Assume each element of the array takes up constant space)

Comment: After throwing around various ideas unsuccessfully, I decided to try to read up on in-place permutations and was led to a paper solving exactly this problem; so, here is a [spoiler](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598). Not sure if I'm breaking protocol by posting this link, so if you'd like me to delete this comment, let me know. Great problem, by the way. I saw how to rotate a cycle on my own but got stuck when it came to finding an element in the "next" cycle.

Comment: @Mitch: No need to delete. Your comment is perfectly appropriate.